# React BrowserRouter - how to programmatically navigate to different routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router

I currently have this in my app.js file:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<div>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={CompOne}/>
        <Route path="/two" component={CompTwo} />
    </Switch>
</div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In my CompOne, I want to programmatically navigate to CompTwo. I know I can use `window.location` to navigate to the /two path, but I would like to pass in some props to CompTwo.

How would I go about programmatically navigating from CompOne to CompTwo while passing in props?

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to do it is to  make use of `history.push()` property so if you want to navigate to `CompTwo` you can do something like this inside `CompOne` :

```
this.props.history.push('/CompTwo');
```